# How to close last-opened tab in gvim?

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

How to close the last opened tab in gvim/windows without quitting gvim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why isn't the regular buffer close working for you? I.e. typing `:bd<CR>`.

Answer (score 0):

You also have `:close<CR>`  which will close the current tab but leave the file in the buffer list